# Grails Executing a query

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hsqldb

I have a table I make in my app known as Meeting. In Meeting you can choose two people to meet, a string date, and a string location. I want to display the Meetings for each individual coming up soon. So on the index page I have a controller

```
package collegenowapp

import collegenowapp.Meeting
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured

@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_COORDINATOR', 'ROLE_LIAISON'])
class IndexController {

def index() { 
        def sql = "select * from Meeting"
        def results = Meeting.executeQuery(sql);
        [results:results]
}
}
```

Then in the index.gsp I use this

```
<%-- The list for meeting --%>
<ul>
    <g:each in="${results}" var="result">
        <li>${result}</li>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```

The page gives me an error saying the * is not allowed, I switch it to the word "date" and then the whole page doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are doing the GORM call wrong:

```
def springSecurityService

def index() { 
  def loggedIn = springSecurityService.currentUser
  def results = Meeting.findAllByUser loggedIn, params
  [results:results]
}
```

Comment: This actually didn't do anything. The list doesn't show up at all. Also, I was trying to put the sql in so I could get a certain persons meetings.

Comment: either the table is empty, or `${result}` returns an invalid html-entity. the later can be fixed by `${result.encodeAsHTML()}`

Comment: That does get the list working. Only problem is I can't filter it. If I use another result set in my controller to try and filter the other the list just doesn't display then. This solution displays all the Meetings, and I want to just display the meetings specific to the user that logs in. How the heck do I query this way?

Comment: One last question. I did `def search = Teacher.findAllByUsername(loggedIn, params)` and then did `def results = Meeting.findAllByTeacher(search, params)` It worked, however I want to also be able to do the same thing but with a user named Liaison instead of teacher. I keep trying to check the logged in user's role and use the Liaison if you are a liaison and Teacher if you're a teacher. However, the check seems successful but the list will not show up on the page....thanks for everything too you do awesome work.

Comment: `def search = Teacher.findByUsername(loggedIn)` would be correct

Comment: Can you tell me why this code only works for one or the other instance? Do I need to do something with params?

`def current = springSecurityService.currentUser.username
def liaisonCheck = Liaison.findAllByUsername(current, params)
def teacherCheck = Teacher.findAllByUsername(current, params)
    
def liaisonMeetingResults = Meeting.findAllByLiaison(liaisonCheck, params)
[liaisonMeetingResults:liaisonMeetingResults]

def teacherMeetingResults = Meeting.findAllByTeacher(teacherCheck, params)
[teacherMeetingResults:teacherMeetingResults]`

Comment: answering the comment would be a brutal off-topic here. open another question for that